# How to prove a valid argument? (discrete math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

"If I eat all night,then I can get fat.If I get fat then I will have a boyfriend.Therefore,if I eat all night, then I will have a boyfriend."

Is the following a valid argument, according to what you know about logic?

here's my solution:

```
    Let:
    A) I eat all night
    B) I can get fat
    C) I will have a boyfriend
```

so
$$A \to B$$
$$B \to C$$

therefore
$$A \to C$$

so it is a valid argument.

But I think I need to do something more, please help?

Comment: It seems that you're using B to represent both "I can get fat" (in the "A implies B" part) and "I get fat" (in the "B implies C" part). So the argument seems to use an unstated assumption:  If I can get fat then I get fat.

Comment: A:I eat all night Let B:I get fat Let C:I will have a boyfriend

Comment: what did I do wrong?

Comment: You represented the first assumption as "A implies B" which means, with your explanation of A and of B, "If I eat all night then I get fat." But the first assumption is actually "If I eat all night, then I **can** get fat."

Comment: It is a mistake that I forgot to type "can"

Comment: With your new version of B, the second assumption is "If I **can** get fat then I will have a boyfriend." But the second assumption is actually "If I get fat then I will have a boyfriend."  (Did you forget to type another "can" in the second hypothesis?)

Answer (score 0):

You can show the validity of the argument applying the definition. An argument is *valid* **iff** :

> there is no possible situation in which the premisses would be true and the conclusion false.

Being an example of *propositional logic*, you can do it using *valuations*, i.e. :

> there is **no** valuation $v$ that satisfy all premisses and does not satisfy the conclusion.